# If I delete the sound library from GarageBand on my Mac, can I reinstall it later for free?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, storage, garageband

I have a MacBook Air and it doesn't have very much storage so I want to delete the sound library from garage band (not the whole app, just the sound library). if I do this, will I be able to reinstall it later for free, or will I have to pay?

Comment: I believe after every update it will re-install itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from [App Store here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garageband/id682658836?mt=12)

It is free, but you will have to use your App Store ID to get it.

[image]

[More Info from Apple](https://www.apple.com/mac/garageband/)